# Unity collider OnTriggerEnter not getting called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've made many **colliders** before and that I used was (collider other`OnTriggerEnter(collider other)`) and then check if the other collider is the one I want by comparing **TAG**. But this time I'm not triggering the canMelee boolean. My code:

```
ArrayList Enemy;
public StatData stat;

[SerializeField]
private bool canMelee = false;

/// <summary>
/// OnTriggerEnter is called when the Collider other enters the trigger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="other">The other Collider involved in this collision.</param>
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Debug.Log("Now you can do melee attack!");
        canMelee = true;
    }
}
```

So I wrote this code but somehow this doesn't work I checked the tag and added it to the player game object but it still doesn't work.

I tried to add another debug to check if OnTriggerEnter() is happening just above the if branch : `Debug.Log("Triggered");` and it gets triggered.

I can't just figure put what's wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and placing a breakpoint on the if block? You can then check what the tag of "col" is by inspecting it. 

I suspect that maybe you have set the parent gameobject tag or something similar.

Could you maybe post a screenshot of having the object selected?

Comment: Can't tell you whats wrong, there are several things can cause this issue(And several others like it).  We need to know your GameObjects Components.  Include a screenshot of the 2 GameObjects Inspector. Including their layers and tags.

Comment: Also have you tried printing out `col.tag`  instead of `"Triggered"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First double check that your enemy game objects have the tag "Enemy". Next make sure that your player collider has the "Is Trigger" option selected in the Unity inspector.

Next try using 
`col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")`
instead of: `col.tag == "Enemy"` in your if statement.

Check out the Unity documentation as well on Colliders:
[Unity Collider documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) 
[Unity Component.CompareTag method with example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The player object doesn't necessarily need to be a trigger. only one of the objects need to be marked as a trigger for "OnTriggerEnter" to be called on both objects.

Comment: I just found that it detects collision for everything except the enemy void OnTriggerEnter(Collider EnemyCol)
 {
  Debug.Log("ENTERED!");
  if (EnemyCol.CompareTag("Enemy"))
  {
   canMelee = true;
  }
 } So what might be wrong?

Comment: As Eddge was saying, it is hard to tell what is exactly wrong without seeing the GameObjects in the inspector. There could be a missing component from one of the objects that could be causing the problem or something else which is only visible in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks Dillon I forgot to put a collider on enemy.

Answer (score 0):

The first advice I can give you, is ALWAYS, when writting a code `Debug` it, just make always sure that every step in your code is beeing executed. Inside every if just debug what it is supposed to check and if its true, inside your void, make sure its running the void, etc...

Next: 
-Check if you have your object tagged as "Enemy", this can be on of the most common errors, and its so easy to solve, you may have written it wrong, or just not set it up.
-Here is the trigger documentation[documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html).
-After this, make sure your `gameobject` is market as `triggered`.

-If you want you can use also [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html), and this also shows you how to check the tag.

Make sure you set all of this up, if this doesn't helped you, comment bellow, with prints, your gameobjects, codes, etc related to this.